# curl doesn't work from Pentaho Data Integration

Tags: curl, pentaho, pentaho-data-integration

I would like to execute the following curl from a transformation using the Execute a process step:

```
curl -X POST --header 'SOAPAction;' --basic --user 'admin:12345' 'http://111.111.111.111:8075/kettle/executeTrans?rep=pent_repo_local&trans=get_tbl'
```

But I get the following error:

```
* Trying 111.111.111.111:8075...
* TCP_NODELAY set
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0* Connected to 111.111.111.111 (111.111.111.111) port 8075 (#0)
* Server auth using Basic with user 'cluster'
> POST /kettle/executeTrans?rep=pent_repo_local&trans=get_tbl HTTP/1.1
> Host: 111.111.111.111:8075
> Authorization: Basic Y2x1c3Rl
> User-Agent: curl/7.68.0
> Accept: */*
> SOAPAction:
>
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 302 Found
< Date: Mon, 24 Jan 2022 05:39:30 GMT
< Location: http://111.111.111.111:8075/kettle/executeTrans/?rep=pent_repo_local&trans=get_tbl
< Content-Length: 0
< Server: Jetty(9.4.18.v20190429)
<
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
* Connection #0 to host 111.111.111.111 left intact
```

I execute the same command directly on the terminal and works fine.
I'm using the 9.2 version of PDI on a Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything was decided like this:

```
curl -L -X POST --header 'SOAPAction;' --basic --user 'admin:12345' 'http://111.111.111.111:8075/kettle/executeTrans?rep=pent_repo_local&trans=get_tbl'
```